# Documentation for strange javascript function definition syntax? () => {}

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

So, I was reading through a js file the other day and noticed a very strange syntax for what I perceived to be a short-hand function definition. I thought it could possibly be related to a library of some kind but I coded up an example in JSFiddle using pure javascript and it does indeed work.

Has anyone seen this before?  Could you point me to documentation for it so I could read a little more about it?  What's the significance of the `'>'` symbol after the `'='`?

Sample:

```
() => {
  alert('hi');
}
```

And here's the [code in use on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dun40o4t/)

Comment: You are looking at [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which has limited availability across browsers at this point. Some precompilers like Typescript/Coffeescript does pollyfill them for ES5..

Comment: FWIW, this function can be simplified to `() => alert('hi')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work in my browser (Chrome). Which probably means you're using Firefox. Mozilla is quick in implementing new Ecmascript features. Arrows are a feature of Ecmascript 6.

> Arrows are a function shorthand using the => syntax. They are syntactically similar to the related feature in C#, Java 8 and CoffeeScript. They support both expression and statement bodies. Unlike functions, arrows share the same lexical this as their surrounding code.

You can read more about Ecmascript 6 features here:
https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features

Edit: Since the native support for arrows is limited at this point, you might have encountered CoffeeScript in the js file you were reading through.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Firefox, and the project was firefox-specific so it makes sense.